# One-way folder sync using symlinks

Tags: rsync, symlink

I’m trying to one-way sync the content of a folder (`public`) to another (`private`) recursively using symbolic links.

```
/public
    /foo
        textfile
    /foo2
/private
    /foo (symlink → ../public/foo)
    /foo2 (symlink → ../public/foo2)
    /foo3
        private-file
```

When a content from `public` is deleted (folder included), it should be deleted from `private` as well.

I tried different methods, using `lndir`, `cp -as` and `rsync`.

I could always write a bash script that loop over `public` folders and symlink them on `private` while deleting broken symlinks as well.
However, this would require executing this job periodically which I'm trying to avoid.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: If what you are really after is real-time instant sync then have a look at the inotify-tools package which will allow you to recursively wait for new files and directories and perform some pre-defined action (in your case involving symlinks) on those changed files/folders.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks for your suggestion !